# Can't view the full equation for the android calculator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator, eclipse-adt

I am done with an android calculator using eclipse ADT
It is working fine but **I can't view the whole equation when I calculate** which means during the testing when I was calculating I couldn't view the whole equation *x+y=z* I was only able to view X and then when I press + I couldn't see on the screen then I saw Y when I clicked it and then I had the answer Z why can't I view the whole equation? **X+Y=Z** here is my java code

```
package com.zee.sampleCalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.zee.sampleCalculator.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 public String str ="";
 Character op = 'q';
 int i,num,number;
 EditText showResult;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);  
    }

    public void btn1Clicked(View v){
       insert(1);   
    }

    public void btn2Clicked(View v){
       insert(2);   
    }

    public void btn3Clicked(View v){
       insert(3);  
    }

    public void btn4Clicked(View v){
       insert(4); 
    }

    public void btn5Clicked(View v){
       insert(5); 
    }

    public void btn6Clicked(View v){
       insert(6);
    }

    public void btn7Clicked(View v){
       insert(7);
    }

    public void btn8Clicked(View v){
       insert(8); 
    }

    public void btn9Clicked(View v){
       insert(9); 
    }

    public void btn0Clicked(View v){
       insert(0);   
    }

    public void btnplusClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '+';
    }

    public void btnminusClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '-';
    }

    public void btndivideClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '/';
    }

    public void btnmultiClicked(View v){
       perform();
       op = '*';
    }

    public void btnequalClicked(View v){
       calculate(); 
    }

    public void btnclearClicked(View v){
       reset();
    }

    private void reset() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       str ="";
       op ='q';
       num = 0;
       number = 0;
       showResult.setText("");
    }

    private void insert(int j) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       str = str+Integer.toString(j);
       num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
       showResult.setText(str);
   }

   private void perform() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      str = "";
      number = num;
   }

   private void calculate() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(op == '+')
         num = number+num;
      else if(op == '-')
         num = number-num;
      else if(op == '/')
         num = number/num;
      else if(op == '*')
         num = number*num;
      showResult.setText(""+num);
   }

}
```

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your perform() method to this:

```
private void perform(String op){
   str = str + op;
   number = num;
   showResult.setText(str);
}
```

and use

```
perform(op);
```

in your btnplusClicked(View v), btnminusClicked(View v), btndivideClicked(View v), btnmultiClicked(View v) to call it.

Now perform() method will add to str +-/* and dont reset it to " ".

And in your calculate method do this:

```
private void calculate(){
   int result;

   if(op == '+')
      result = number+num;
   else if(op == '-')
      result = number-num;
   else if(op == '/')
      result = number/num;
   else if(op == '*')
      result = number*num;
   showResult.setText(number + " " + op + " " + num + " = " + result);
}
```

If you dont understand something, dont worry to ask. I hope this helps you :)

**EDIT1:**

I made a small mistake. You are using char, not String.

```
public void btnplusClicked(View v){
   op = '+';
   perform(op);
}

private void perform(char op){
   ...
}
```

and in calculate()

```
private void calculate(){
   int result = 0;
   ...
}
```

Now, it should work. But as far i know, you dont understand main basics of Java and its types. Android is java based and its necessary to understand a little bit from Java until you start programming in Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot in the beginning I did as u said in the first code but in the 2nd one preform(op); did u meant to make it like this  
`public void btnplusClicked(View v){
       perform(op);
       op = '+';
      }`
because when I did an error showed up which is _The method perform(String) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments(Character)_ and in the last code I got an error in ShowResult.setText the result which is in the last was marked as an error _The local variable result may have not been initialized_ *Hope you will help me to solve these errors.* Thanks again.

Comment: **Thanks a lot** I will check it again now :D I know Java but still I need to learn much more.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code does exactly what you are asking it to do. In order to see the entire equation you will have to change some things.

```
private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = ""; //get the value in showResult by doing showResult.getText()
              // and keep appending to the string.
    number = num;
   }
```

also in your :

```
private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(op == '+')
     num = number+num;
    else if(op == '-')
     num = number-num;
    else if(op == '/')
     num = number/num;
    else if(op == '*')
     num = number*num;
    showResult.setText(number+ " " + op + " " + num + " " + "=" + num); // change this to 
   }
```

I haven't tried it out but this should move you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help @android_Muncher ..
but if you please tell me more about the first code I didn't get it.
and in the second code in the show.Result.setText I am getting syntax error in this area + num " " +  should I delete " " ?
Sorry but I am new in this whole thing I am not that expert when it is about Java.